# Invalid user credentials: redirect user to another page or display a message?

Tags: javascript, redirect, servlets, authentication

I have created a login page using HTML and JS. It has a form and a submit button. When a user enters invalid credentials, an error message is displayed on same page (it is displayed below the form). However, Facebook, GMail, Hotmail, etc, redirect the user to another page if credentials are incorrect. Why do they choose that approach? Is it related to security? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's primarily a matter of personal choice. If you are creating a single page app with angular or the likes, the cleanest (and my preferred) method is to do as you are and display the error message there. If you want the error to be more "meaty", a redirect serves your purpose. Usually displaying the error on the same page is sufficient though.